# TRS connector for noice cancelling headphones has 5 wires inside cable, instead of 4

Tags: audio, cables, repair, headphones

Scenario: 3.5mm TRS audio connector on a pair of Panasonic RP-HC200 Noise Cancelling headpohones is damaged, so I cut it off and I'm going to replace the connector from another pair. After cutting and opening the jacket, I find 5 wires (Red, Gold, Blue, Green, and blue/gold-stripe, as per attached photo). I was expecting a standard 4: one pair for each driver. What is that fifth wire for? Where would I hook it up?

[image: severed TRS headphone cable containing 5 wires: Red, Gold, Blue, Green, and blue/gold-stripe]

Now, as I understand, "noise cancelling" is usually done with a tiny microphone on the outside of the headphones to sample the environmental sound to produce a "negating" sound via circuitry embedded in the headphones' "cans", but I would have expected all of that to remain inside the headphones, no need to send the signal down the cable. And moreover, since its still TRS (not TRRS), I don't see where it would be hooked up.

Comment: there's probably just two ground conductors, one for each side.

Comment: I am also about to do this with the same model, did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd do is closely examine that original plug.  Cut it apart if you have to - See inside and see if you can figure it out by examination.

That said, it'd take some knowledge of that particular headphone design to know exactly what each wire does.

Is there insulation on the 'clear' looking wire???   If not, that may be a drain wire for the shield.